# Users activity feed in orchard cms

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

we are working on orchard, we need to create a activity feed of users,means all the activities of users like updations,deletions, or insertions of their details neddto be shownas they did in their home page.  how to create custom  activity feed using  orchard cms? or is there any existing design for that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can intercept "activities" on user details by creating a content handler for the UserPart like so

```
public class MyHandler : Orchard.ContentManagement.Handlers.ContentHandler
{
  // public
    public MyHandler()
    {
      // listen to user events
      OnPublishing<Orchard.Users.Models.UserPart>(UserPublishing);
      OnRemoving<Orchard.Users.Models.UserPart>(UserRemoving);
      ...
    }

  // private
    private void UserPublishing(Orchard.ContentManagement.Handlers.PublishContentContext aContext, Orchard.Users.Models.UserPart aUserPart)
    {
      // do some stuff on user publishing
    }

    private void UserRemoving(Orchard.ContentManagement.Handlers.RemoveContentContext aContext, Orchard.Users.Models.UserPart aUserPart)
    {
      // do some stuff on user removal
    }

    ...
}
```

Extensive documentation can be found here:
http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Understanding-content-handlers/

There is also a module called Orchard Audit which seems to record user activities:
http://gallery.orchardproject.net/Packages/Orchard.Module.Downplay.Audit